# Samsung Galaxy Note - why KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL events are generated when its stylus touches/releases the screen?

Tags: android, galaxy, forward-delete

Samsung Galaxy Note has a stylus and I am observing a strange behavior when the stylus touches/leaves the screen.

In addition to expected series of SessionView.onTouchEvent calls, SessionView.onKeyDown/SessionView.onKeyUp calls are received when the stylus touches/leaves the screen. The KeyEvent code for SessionView.onKeyDown/SessionView.onKeyUp calls is 112 (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL), scancode 555.

Also pressing/releasing butoon on the stylus results in  SessionView.onKeyDown/SessionView.onKeyUp calls with KeyEvent code 114 (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_RIGHT), scancode 544.

The event source for the KeyEvent is reported as 257 (InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD) which makes this indistinguishable from keyboard event and messes up keyboard functionality in our app, because stylus touches produce unexpected DEL key presses.

I am wondering if anybody can shed some more light on this behavior. Is it just a proprietary hack by Samsung developers to implement stylus functionality on Android 2.3? What would be a robust way to handle this?

Device details:

```
Device model: GT-N7000
Firmware version: 2.3.6
Kernel version: 2.6.35.7-N7000XXLA4-CL886827
se.infra@SEP-74 )
#2 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 12 21:15:11 KST 2012
Build number: GINGERBREAD.XXLA4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could see KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL is a new field in API Level 11. So The key code 112 should be a code defined by Samsung.

Use Java reflection in the method onKeyDown() according to the following code. We could get
112 is KEYCODE_PEN in the system.

```
Field[] fields = event.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
    if (f.getType().equals(int.class)) {
        try {
            TLog.i(TAG, f.getName() + ": " + f.getInt(event));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```